# Change a string representation of a list into a numpy array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a string representation of a list, such as the result of `str([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])`; `'[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]'`. How can I convert this to a numpy array? I have tried the below code.

```
import numpy as np

a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
b = str(a)
c = np.array(b, dtype=float)
```

My expected output is:

```
>>> c
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Comment: Why not just `np.array` on `a`? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: it is just a list of lists.

Comment: Your question is unclear please include expected input/output

Comment: try this, if you want to make an array:  c=numpy.array([numpy.array(ap) for ap in a])

Comment: You specify dtype=float so you should expect float and not int I guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is really what you want to do, and not just `np.array(a)`, you could use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert `b` back to a list as follows:

```
>>> import ast
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> b = str(a)
>>> np.array(ast.literal_eval(b), dtype=float)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import json

a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
b = str(a)
c = np.array(json.loads(b), dtype=float)
```